# Registry setting to add underline in context menu for keyboard navigation

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, context-menu

By right click on any file or folder, it comes out a context menu. In that menu, how to add a keyboard shortcut to a self-added entry? (keyboard navigation, one key to execute a certain entry)

I added the new entry here (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try placing "&" symbol in entry name before the letter you want to make shortcut from, e.g.: "&Open", "C&lose".